# Partial Derivatives of Special Functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

We have a function$ f$ of class $C^2$ such that $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)∈\Re^2$. Why the partial derivatives are $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}{f(x,y)}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}{f(y,x)}$ ?. An example of this type of functions.

Comment: Writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}{f(x,y)}$ is very ambiguous: assume that $f(x,y)=x+y^2$ (it doesn't satisfy the given condition $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$, but this is just to point out that something is wrong with the notation). Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}{(x,y)} = 2y$, while defining $g(x,y)=f(y,x) = y+x^2$ yields $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}{(x,y)} = 1$...

Answer (score 0):

The identity doesn't hold in general,

\begin{align*}
  f(x,y) &= x^2y-xy^2 \\
  f(y,x) &= y^2x-yx^2 \\
  &= -f(x-y) \\
  \frac{\partial (x^2y-xy^2)}{\partial y}
  &= x^2-2xy \\
  \frac{\partial (y^2x-x^2y)}{\partial x}
  &= y^2-2xy
\end{align*}